# Coordinate Transformation on Local coordinate system

Tags: geometry, physics, 3d, coordinate-systems, quaternions

I am having a point $P(x,y,z)$ in $3D$ with respect to global coordinate system. I want to create an another Local  Coordinate System by picking three points $N1, N2, N3$ in 3D. Now I want to know the new coordinate values of the point $P'(x', y', z')$ with respect to the Local Coordinate System.

Please suggest me to create correct transformation matrix, or any procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, and thank you for your question.  We will be able to better answer it if you give more context, as well as defining the terms you are using, like Local Coordinate System.  Lastly, it will help us if you tell us anything you've tried or progress you've made so far.

Comment: @vadim123, Thanks for your quick response. The point which I created first is with respect to $(0,0,0)$. Now I am re-position the origin at somewhere in the 3D space. by specifying another three vectors. I have tried with directional cosines.

Comment: Known: $(x,y,z)$ origin of the global coordinate system. Point $P(x1,y1,z1)$. Looking for: (1)Construct new reference point $P'(x2,y2,z2)$ (2) $P$'s coordinate values $(x1',y1',z1')$ with respect to New Reference point $P'(x2,y2,z2)$

Comment: Describing a rotation simply as “clockwise” is hardly approproate for a 3D rotation. You should specify the axis of rotation along with that. Once you have that, you can come up with a rotation matrix and then apply that to your coordinates.

Comment: @MvG Thanks for your reply. You are right. I have created a point in 3D $(x,y,z)$ successfully. My second task is to create new reference point. To create a new reference point in 3D, I am using $i, j, k$ vector calculation to determine the directions. Your valuable suggestions to create a new reference point would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks to all. I found the solution: $v1 = n2 - n1; t = n3 - n1; v3 = n1 X t; v2 = v3 X v1;$

Comment: When you have found the answer, feel free to post a answer to your own question. That will also remove it from the “unanswered” queue, which is a good thing. In formulas, you might want to write `\times` instead of `X` for the cross product.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$P' = T^{-1}.R_x(\theta).T.P $