# Transform 3 points' coordinates from one coordinate system to another one's

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

I have 3 known points in the Cartesian, let's say, World coordinate system:

$P^W_1= (10, 10, 10)$,

$P^W_2= (10, 12, 10)$,

$P^W_3= (5, 10, 12)$.

There is a point $L$ in the World system which "sees" these 3 points with the coordinates:

$P^L_1= (3, -2, 1)$,

$P^L_2= (3, -4, 1)$,

$P^L_3= (8, -2, 3)$.

I would like find and expression $T$ that can be used to calculate any arbitrary point's $W$ coordinate from the $L$ system, or for that matter, from any coordinate system given that we know the coordinates of that 3 points.

[Coordinate transformation based on three points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2059833/coordinate-transformation-based-on-three-points) gave me some ideas about the solution to this problem, but the answer there assumes the same origin of the two coordinate systems.

[Coordinate Transformation on Local coordinate system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373194/coordinate-transformation-on-local-coordinate-system) has pretty much the same problem but it's answer is rather confusing to me.

I tried finding the coordinates of $L$ and then finding a transformation $T$ so that $T(L)=(0,0,0)$, but to no avail.

This method, I presume,  could be done using a system of linear equations $Ax=B$, where $A$ is the points' coordinate in $L$ and $B$ in $W$, however, I do not really know where to start.

If you could direct me to a relevant thread I might have missed or give some hints, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I found that the normal unit vectors in spherical coordinates are $(1,0,0.3805)$ and $(1,\pi,0.3805)$ respectively to the 2 coordinate systems. Does this help any way?